# Can't find javascript that's changing focus

Tags: javascript, magento, google-chrome-devtools

I have a magento installation an on product listing pages there's contact form at the side. The problem is whenever the page loads the focus is set to the name field of the form which is really undesired.

If you [follow the link](http://divinecreations.net/trousseau-packing/first-card-concept.html), you'll see what happens. I tried using breakpoints but it's like a dead end. The function it points to seems to do nothing of this sort. 
[image: Set Breakpoint on field]

---

[image: Culprit Function]
The function dev tools points at:

```
responder = function(event) {
          Event.extend(event, element);
          handler.call(element, event);
};
```

Is it possible to have more information from dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove default focus from form's field by changing script added at form's bottom to following

```
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', false);
//]]>
```

The second parameter passed to `VarienForm` is responsible for auto focus on form's first field.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but can you explain how you reached this conclusion? BTW I did change that to false but there was no difference. Check the link again

Comment: Wait. It worked! I forgot to clear the cache. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a jQuery solution. Please check with your code.

```
$(function () {
    $('input').blur();
});
```